# In what ways is this XOR encryption system vulnerable?

Tags: security, encryption, xor, password-encryption

I am looking into simple ways to secure the many passwords I have for my online accounts. After some thought I came up with this idea:

1. Change all my current passwords to be random streams of ASCII characters.
2. Using a memorized master key, encrypt each password using a simple XOR (password ^ key).
3. Store the results of the encryption somewhere (presumably accessible by an attacker).
4. When I want to retrieve a password, repeat the XOR operation with my master key.

I am wondering if there are any vulnerabilities in this system. The master key length will be at least the length of the longest random password, so there will be no repetition of the key within a single password but the key will be the same for each encrypted password. In essence this is a sort of reverse Vernam Cipher; the key is not random but the "plaintext" (passwords) is. How could an attacker exploit this system? Is it possible to break?

Comment: What's the benefit over using the same password for every system?

Comment: Now that I understand how an attacker could obtain all my passwords after acquiring only one of them, the benefit is very marginal. One benefit would be only having to remember a single password, since not all systems accept all passwords (for example, one system might require at least one non-alphanumeric character for its passwords, and another might allow only alphanumeric characters), so it might not be possible to use the same password for every system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as an OTP scheme where the key is reused. Those schemes can be easily broken: XOR two encrypted passwords with each other, you get P1 ^ P2. Now if a character of P1 or P2 is identical you get a 0 output. If they are almost the same, you get something that has only a single bit set (etc.). Once you guess one password, you can XOR it with the encrypted password to get the key. The only bits that are safe are the characters at the end of the longest password (if the key is not repeated).

This cryptoanalysis is given as the first practice for new cryptographers in most text books. It is completely unsafe.

Comment: Not to mention, when you can choose your own password and see the stored "encrypted" value, you know the key.

Comment: Ah this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. This could be solved then by using a longer key and using unique sections of it to encrypt each password, perhaps? For example, if I had 4 passwords, each 8 characters long, then I could use a 32 character key.

Comment: OTP is kind of a theoretical construct. For it to be used the key should be the same size as the plaintext and fully random. Now in theory you can remember a 32 byte, fully random key, but I guess it would be easier to remember 4 distinct passwords. I would suggest to use a password manager on your (possibly disused if you are really security conscientious) smart phone instead. If you can use a computer generally there are better options than OTP.

Comment: Okay thank you, good advice. One last question - let's say I used something very non-random for my long key (a poem, a phrase that only I know, etc.), but since the passwords themselves are random (assume for simplicity that they are "fully random"), that has the same effect, right? Even with the correct key/phrase, the attacker will not know that the passwords have been correctly decrypted without actually trying to log in to a service with them (which is generally very slow because of incorrect-password lockouts and such).

Comment: If one of the two sides used in an OTP scheme is fully random and is not reused then you should be OK. But again, using OTP is in general not very useful. To create an OTP like key stream, you could use a stream cipher (such as Salsa20) or a block cipher in streaming mode (such as AES-CTR).

Answer (score 1):

This is borderline useless. All an attacker must do is get one of your passwords and he has all your passwords. So you're as secure as the least secure system you use this scheme for. One login from a public WiFi network without SSL and you're *done*.

Answer (score 1):

Don't invent your own Crypto functions...The password storage problem is not new.

The XOR encryption is very easy to break, check this [SANS blog](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2013/05/14/tools-for-examining-xor-obfuscation-for-malware-analysis)

Here is a better alternative:

The best known way to protect passwords is to use salted password hashing. I recommend that you use the SHA256 function, this is implemented in most modern programming languages.

Hash algorithms are one way functions. This means that you can not decrypt the stored password.

The general workflow for account registration and authentication in a hash-based system is as follows:

1. User creates an account
2. You hash the password+salt and store the result in your Database
3. At the nextLogin attempt, you hash the entered password+salt and compare that with the value in the database

Now the only thing we still need to do is define the Salt:

1. The salt does not need to be a secret! its only there to prevent rainbow attacks
2. The salt needs to be unique per-user per-password. A random generated string of sufficient length will do the job.
3. Every time a user creates an account or changes their password, the password should be hashed using a new random salt.

The salt can be stored in the user account table alongside the hash.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about password storage for a password manager, where password retrieval is a key requirement, but that problem has also been solved many times and in a (far more) secure fashion.

Comment: Hashing is good if you don't need the plaintext password later, but a simple hash of the SHA-* family is ways too fast. Instead use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2 with a cost factor.

Comment: Damien is right, but this was also very helpful. Thank you Frank.